# Add new point to feature class but keep numbering scheme

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, table

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I need to add a point to a feature class. The objects are named based on spatial attributes, ie one point is named 1364, the next one down is 1365 etc. I need to add a point that will be called "1365" while making the current 1365 into "1366" and so on for the remaining points.

How can I do this?

Comment: Far better to keep track of what you want the IDs to be, then process the table into a new table with IDs in the order you want.